# Mount error (112) - Host is down, specifying SMB protocol version does not resolve issue

Tags: mount, ubuntu-18.04, cifs

Hoping someone can help.

I have previously been able to mount a local network drive to my server (was running Ubuntu 16.04.7, now running 18.04.6).  However, recently when I try it gives the following error:

`mount error(112): Host is down`

I use the command below to mount:

`mount /mnt/directoryname`

My fstab looks like:

`//network/share/ /mnt/directoryname cifs uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,noauto,user 0 0`

Having read through previous posts with similar issues, I have attempted to force the use of specific SMB protocols (1, 2, 2.1 and 3), using the following fstab (in this example for version 1):

`//network/share/ /mnt/directoryname cifs uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,noauto,user,vers=1.0 0 0`

No matter which version I specify I continue to get the same error.

If I comment out the line in the fstab and attempt to mount via the command-line I continue to receive the same error.  Below is the mount options I use:

`sudo mount -t cifs //network/share/ /mnt/directoryname -o username=myusername,vers=1.0`

I have also seen the addition of "defaults" to the fstab options:

`//network/share/ /mnt/directoryname cifs uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,noperm,noauto,defaults,user 0 0`

but that just produces an invalid argument error message (so perhaps I added it incorrectly).

I'm not sure what to do now.  I can connect to the network drive via my PC and the webpage.  I can ping the network drive from the server.  Therefore, I know it is up and running.

I have tried using smbclient as well:

`smbclient //network/share/ --user=MYUSERNAME`

That gives the following error:

`protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED`

Which possibly has more to do with the fact I don't really know how to use the smbclient command but may be indicative of an associated issue.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Thank you for reading.

ETA: correct mount command when commenting out the fstab line

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has already reached it's end of life, it does not get security updates anymore. You should upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: I have now upgraded to 18.04 and I am still having the same issue.